# YouTube API get current shorts video title/duration/position

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

```js
player = document.getElementById('movie_player'); 
player.getVideoData().title
```

It works, but not for shorts. Any idea how to get these info with shorts videos?

Edit: it seems that `document.title` does the trick.
But is there any way to get duration and position then? `getDuration` and `getCurrentTime` do not seem to work on shorts.

Comment: have you checked the [docs?](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information) and https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status?

Comment: what i tried is getDuration and getCurrentTime, that work for regular videos, but not for shorts. The docs you link seem to refer to these methods to get those data?

Comment: Since shorts are a new feature, I don't know if said functions are up to date for shorts, please, try what is available on the documentation and then, [edit] your question with your code and results. If nothing works, it might be worth it to post an issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc)